# Issue with multiple forms on one page: button submits the wrong form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I am writing a website version of a part of our windows application. It's basicaly a calendar. People can view Appointments and edit them. For every Appointment i have a form wich is hidden an will only be shown when a user clicks a link. Now the problem is only the form of the first appointment on a page works. If I click the submit button of another form it will actually submit the first form. Here's is the code generating the form:

```
 <div class="popupbox" id="popuprel@{@mit.Id_mit}_@{@day.Day}">
 @for (int i = 0; i < tcsForDay.Count; i++)
 {
     <p>
     @tcsForDay[i].Tag_child.Zeitvo - @tcsForDay[i].Tag_child.Zeitna <br />
     @if (tcsForDay[i].Subtype != null)
     {
           @:( @tcsForDay[i].Subtype.Type) @tcsForDay[i].Tag_child.Text
           <a href="#" rel="AppForm@{@mit.Id_mit}_@{@day.Day}_@{@i}" class="AppEditLink">Editieren</a>

     }
     else
     {
           @:( @Model.typeTagesEinteilung.Type) @tcsForDay[i].Tag_child.Text
           <a href="#" rel="AppForm@{@mit.Id_mit}_@{@day.Day}_@{@i}">Edit</a>
     }
     </p>
     <div id="AppForm@{@mit.Id_mit}_@{@day.Day}_@{@i}"class="AppForm">

     @{
           string formname = String.Format("AppFormForm{0}_{1}_{2}", mit.Id_mit, day.Day, i);
     }
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Plan", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "AppFormForm", name = formname }))
     {

          @Html.Hidden("tagchild_id", tcsForDay[i].Tag_child.Id_tagchild);
          @Html.Label("Text")<br />
          @Html.TextBox("Text", null, new { @class = "required" })<br />
          @Html.Label("Zeit Von")<br />
          @Html.TextBox("ZeitVon", null, new { @class = "required time" })<br />
          @Html.Label("Zeit Nach")<br />
          @Html.TextBox("ZeitNach", null, new { @class = "required time" })<br />

          <input type="submit" value="Speichern" name="button@{@mit.Id_mit}_@{@day.Day}_@{@i}" />

      }
      </div>


 }
```

The names may not be obvious. tc or Tag_child is an appointment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the markup for each individual form what do you see?

My guess is that each HTML element is not getting a unique name. If this is the case, then it will never submit the proper form, because it doesn't know the difference between them.

Each form element on your page needs to have a UNIQUE name:

```
<input id="Text1" name="Text1" />

<input id="Text2" name="Text2" />
```

etc.

Comment: that might be the problem. But when i change the names then the model binding wouldn't work. Because i have to name the parameters in the controller the same as name of the input elements. Any idea how to fix this?